# Executing Hudson jobs remotely

Tags: hudson

I am trying to automate Hudson by hitting the appropriate urls remotely. I am using python's urllib2 for doing the same.

First of all , I am trying to build an existing job and get the build status.

A sample url for the build would look like this:

http://tomcaturl:8080/hudson/job/.NET%20Build/build

However this returns to me html data.

Hudson docs say that I can get data in python/json/xml format, so I try to hit

http://tomcaturl:8080/hudson/job/.NET%20Build/build/api/json

But I get no data at all, although the build happens successfully.

Is there a way to find out which build was started by my remote build request, so that I can maintain a one-to-one mapping.

Please note that I am doing this through a remote python program and I DO NOT have access to hudson GUI.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you have any security/login enabled you have to be logged in to the remote hudson server for the /job/JobName/build. If you allow starting the build without being logged in, this is not a problem.

The /job/JobName/build request will return html data. If you are not logged in you will get a repsonse redirecting to the login page and the build will not be started. If the request is successful you will not get a redirect to the login, and you can assume the build was queued. You can also check the build queue using the api url of the project (see below). Note that there may be a delay before the build is started, which you can control by calling /job/JobName/build?delay=0sec

The API is not available under the job/JobName/build  url, but you can see api information here:

http://tomcaturl:8080/hudson/job/.NET%20Build/api

Most pages in hudson that shows information (about a project, a specific build and so on) has an api page if you append /api/xml or /api/json to the end of the url.
The reason /job/JobName/build doesn't have an api page is simply because it isn't an url to an information page.

Example api requests:

xml call for information about the project:

http://tomcaturl:8080/hudson/job/.NET%20Build/api/xml

json call for information about the last successful build of the project:

http://tomcaturl:8080/hudson/job/.NET%20Build/lastSucessfulBuild/api/json

Comment: And the following will simply get you the information of the last build even if it wasn't successful http://http://tomcaturl:8080/hudson/job/.NET%20Build/lastBuild/api/xml or http://http://tomcaturl:8080/hudson/job/.NET%20Build/lastBuild/api/json

Comment: Thanks Anders, and sdmythos_gr.

Comment: Any idea on how I do the mapping, can I make the build call return me a BUILD_ID/BUILD_TAG/BUILD_NUM, or the builds always scheduled.

Comment: I don't think you get any information from the build request. You will know whether it was successful or not I guess, and you can look at the list of builds for the job and see the latest build started by the user in question, this is probably the started build. I could be wrong and there is something returned invisibly in the response that you can use, other than just "OK".

Comment: @sdmythos_gr returns the lastbuild number and some data, like if it is running, if was successful or failed. You can get the return of a specific job with the url: http://tomcaturl:8080/hudson/job/.NET%20Build/<number>/api/json

and you can get the console output with a get in the url: http://tomcaturl:8080/hudson/job/.NET%20Build/<number>/consoleText